# XBee + Arduino Problem

Tags: power, xbee, arduino-mini

I've been doing some XBee experiments with Arduino Pro Mini 5V. I knew that XBee S2 is 3.3V only, so I've connected its Vcc to 3.3V from external supply, but I had also connected XBee RXTX to arduino TXRX, in this order, and since that i can't use my XBee Explorer to communicate with XCTU on my notebook. The connections with an 5V Arduino RXTX can cause damages to the XBee, even if the XBee was powered with 3.3V?

Comment: Try to add a voltage divider on Arduino's TX to shift it to 3.3v logic. This might solve your problem.

Comment: The thing is, I can't even communicate with the XBee with a XBee Explorer to my computer, since I did that. Its problaby bricked or damage. What I wanna know if it can get damaged from the RXTX pins.

Comment: Did you try the opposite wiring? TX --TX and RX -- RX ?

Comment: I've tryed it eventualy as some guides for bricked XBee sugested, but nothing happend.

Comment: Is this the first time you tried to work with this xbee? Was it working before this time? Please tell me how do you connect it to your computer?

Comment: I just started working with XBee this week. Yes, I could do some thing before it "bricked". I've connected it to my computer with an XBee Explorer from Parallax. http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/wireless/zigbee/xbee-usb-adapter

Comment: Just found this on Digi website. "The XBee is a 3.3V only device, connecting 5V to any pin may damage the radio. If you had connected the XBee to a 5V microcontroller or power source, it's possible that the radio is damaged beyond repair". On this link, the last topic, http://knowledge.digi.com/articles/Knowledge_Base_Article/Recovery-procedure-for-ZigBee-XBees. I really think that the XBee is gone. :/

Answer (score 1):

Just found this on Digi website. "The XBee is a 3.3V only device, connecting 5V to any pin may damage the radio. If you had connected the XBee to a 5V microcontroller or power source, it's possible that the radio is damaged beyond repair". On this link, the last topic, knowledge.digi.com/articles/Knowledge_Base_Article/…. I really think that the XBee is gone. One way to avoid this problem is to get one of this regulated breakout board. http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/xbee-explorer-reg. As it says in the description, it regulates ALL pins to 3.3V, making me believe that I needed to take care of that before making such a mistake. Hopefully this prevent someone from doing this mistake in the future. So, bye-bye XBee.

Comment: Based on the information found here: https://www.faludi.com/bwsn/xbee-level-shifting/ . It seems that xbee isn't that sensitive and maybe you can apply 5v logic to RX pin.